# What’s wrong with this idea for an energy generator?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, dissipation, perpetual-motion

Okay I know a perpetuum mobile is impossible, so I think this should be wrong.

I thought about heat pumps with a COP of 3.5, which is like 350% efficiency compared to a simple electrical resistor. Now say you put 100W of electricity into the heat pump, which will pull 350W of heat energy from outside to the inside. Let’s say you can use this energy to boil some liquid (probably not water because of its high boiling point). This liquid turns into a gas and powers a steam (or other vapor) turbine. Now a turbine has an efficiency of 50%, but I’m finding different numbers online. That means that you can use that 350W of heat energy to generate 175W of electricity. Which you can then reuse to power the heat pump, with a surplus of 75W.

Now obviously I’m overlooking something because this shouldn’t be possible.

Others have suggested losses, but that shouldn’t be the culprit here, as with a more efficient setup heat pumps can get a COP of 5, which causes the system to have more room for error.

Comment: A combined cycle power plant with a gas turbine running at 1500 degrees F has that kind of efficiency, but not one running near room temperature.

Comment: I think @FlatterMann has nailed it.

Comment: "A perpetual motion machine is a hypothetical machine that can do work infinitely without an external energy source. "  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion       Heat pumps reallocate heat, cooling the outside air and bringing the heat inside the house, the environment is the energy source. That is what you are overlooking.

Comment: @annav so that means my idea would be possible? It would generate power from the temperature outside?

Comment: https://www.energy.gov/eere/iedo/combined-heat-and-power-basics

Comment: "Now say you put 100W of electricity into the heat pump, which will pull 350W of heat energy from outside to the inside." That's incorrect. The total energy delivered indoors will be 350 w, but the heat pulled in from the outside will be 250 w, not 350 w.

Comment: What's more, you can't just a assume a 50% efficient turbine, which depends on the operating range of temperatures.

Comment: It is also important to note that even in the best case scenario that your COP of 3.5 is coming from the best cycle, Carnot cycle, it would mean that there is a cap on the efficiency of your heat engine to 28.57%, so that the maximum efficiency of the whole process is necessarily less than unity.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the case of the heat pump that I just had installed in my house last month. It operates between an outside air temperature of 40 F and an inside temperature of 68 F which means the heated air coming out of the floor vents is at 68 F.

To keep the house at 68 F requires that the system run continuously, day and night. This means that the output of the system is a very large mass flow rate of air across a relatively small temperature difference. This is exactly the opposite of what's needed *in practice* to run a turbogenerator: a relatively small mass flow rate across the highest possible temperature difference.

The small delta T inescapably means that the heat pump driven heat engine is going to waste almost all of the heat energy it has laboriously collected from its surroundings and extract only a tiny fraction of useful work from it: its *Carnot efficiency* will be negligible.

So while your idea looks like it should work "on paper", the missing part of your analysis is working out the Carnot efficiency of the process and comparing it to  the losses inherent in the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get 50% efficiency from the turbine.  The turbine is a type of heat engine.  The theoretical best efficiency from a heat engine is

$$eff = 1 - \frac{T_c}{T_h}$$

where $T_h$ is the hot reservoir absolute temperature and $T_c$ is the cold sink absolute temperature.  For the temperatures that your heat pump can provide, you will be getting only around 4% theoretical efficiency, or 1-2% actual efficiency, and that's not nearly enough to build a perpetual motion machine.  For much more information, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine).